# Laravel Routing Multi level users with middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

Hello i have 2 level users:
1 Super admin who is able to see and do everthing
2 TD which is able to only see stuff and not change anything

I made 2 middleware:
1 auth.superadmin and 1 auth.td

My routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.superadmin']], function() {
Route::get('/users/{id}/destroy', 'UsersController@destroy');
Route::get('/searchuser', 'UsersController@searchuser');
Route::get('/users/create-worker', 'UsersController@getcreateworker');
Route::post('/users/post-create-worker', 'UsersController@postcreateworker');
Route::get('/users/create-agent', 'UsersController@getcreateagent');
Route::post('/users/post-create-agent', 'UsersController@postcreateagent');
Route::get('/users-optima', 'UsersController@indexoptima');
Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');
Route::patch('/retours/{id}/postupdatefill','RetoursController@postupdatefill');
Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/addpart/{partid}','RetoursController@addpart');
Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/remove/{partid}','RetoursController@removepart');
Route::post('/retours/{retourid}/garantie','RetoursController@postonderdeelgarantie');
Route::get('/retours/{id}/updatefill/searchpart',   'RetoursController@searchpart');
Route::get('/searchpart', 'PartsController@searchpart');
Route::resource('/parts', 'PartsController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.td']], function() {
Route::get('/users/{id}/destroy', 'UsersController@destroy');
Route::get('/searchuser', 'UsersController@searchuser');

Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController',
    ['only' => ['index']]);

Route::patch('/retours/{id}/postupdatefill','RetoursController@postupdatefill');
Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/addpart/{partid}','RetoursController@addpart');
Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/remove/{partid}','RetoursController@removepart');
Route::post('/retours/{retourid}/garantie','RetoursController@postonderdeelgarantie');
Route::get('/retours/{id}/updatefill/searchpart', 'RetoursController@searchpart');
Route::get('/searchpart', 'PartsController@searchpart');
Route::resource('/parts', 'PartsController');
});
```

My middelware:
superadmin

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->level == 1) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return abort(404, 'no entry to this page');
```

TD

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->level == 2) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return abort(404, 'no entry to this page');
```

I tried beginning with /Users. 
TD can only see the index at /Users.

When i do it this way the auth.superadmin cannot see index@/users...

[image]

Am i doing it wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For your own sake, look into using `Route::group(["prefix" => "..."] ... );` instead of repeating your `/users/whatever` routes over and over again

Comment: Will do @TimLewis, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your routes and its groups like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.td']], function() {
    Route::get('/users/{id}/destroy', 'UsersController@destroy');
    Route::get('/searchuser', 'UsersController@searchuser');
    Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController',['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::patch('/retours/{id}/postupdatefill','RetoursController@postupdatefill');
    Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/addpart/{partid}','RetoursController@addpart');
    Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/remove/{partid}','RetoursController@removepart');
    Route::post('/retours/{retourid}/garantie','RetoursController@postonderdeelgarantie');
    Route::get('/retours/{id}/updatefill/searchpart', 'RetoursController@searchpart');
    Route::get('/searchpart', 'PartsController@searchpart');
    Route::resource('/parts', 'PartsController');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.superadmin']], function() {
        Route::get('/users/{id}/destroy', 'UsersController@destroy');
        Route::get('/searchuser', 'UsersController@searchuser');
        Route::get('/users/create-worker', 'UsersController@getcreateworker');
        Route::post('/users/post-create-worker', 'UsersController@postcreateworker');
        Route::get('/users/create-agent', 'UsersController@getcreateagent');
        Route::post('/users/post-create-agent', 'UsersController@postcreateagent');
        Route::get('/users-optima', 'UsersController@indexoptima');
        Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');
        Route::patch('/retours/{id}/postupdatefill','RetoursController@postupdatefill');
        Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/addpart/{partid}','RetoursController@addpart');
        Route::get('/retours/{retourid}/remove/{partid}','RetoursController@removepart');
        Route::post('/retours/{retourid}/garantie','RetoursController@postonderdeelgarantie');
        Route::get('/retours/{id}/updatefill/searchpart',   'RetoursController@searchpart');
        Route::get('/searchpart', 'PartsController@searchpart');
        Route::resource('/parts', 'PartsController');
    });
});
```

and your `auth:td` middleware should be like this:

```
if (auth()->check() && (auth()->user()->level == 1 || auth()->user()->level == 2)) {
  return $next($request);
}
return abort(404, 'no entry to this page');
```

> Just for your knowledge you can either remove the outer middleware (`auth:td`) as both users can use the routes under it. But I haven't done that because I think you have more users in your system.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes this fixed my problem. Thank you very much!